# Branch target address alignment decreases the performance on arm

Tags: performance, arm

I have the following code for getting sum of three vectors:

```
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
                c[i] += a[i] + b[i]
        }
```

On ARMv8 system it gives the following assembly:

```
   fcddc:       f86478c5        ldr     x5, [x6, x4, lsl #3]
   fcde0:       f8647807        ldr     x7, [x0, x4, lsl #3]
   fcde4:       f8647868        ldr     x8, [x3, x4, lsl #3]
   fcde8:       8b070107        add     x7, x8, x7
   fcdec:       8b0500e5        add     x5, x7, x5
   fcdf0:       f82478c5        str     x5, [x6, x4, lsl #3]
   fcdf4:       91000484        add     x4, x4, #0x1
   fcdf8:       eb04003f        cmp     x1, x4
   fcdfc:       54ffff0c        b.gt    fcddc
```

We can see, that the loop body starts at the non-aligned address `fcddc`. According to the arm performance manuals, I try to make the address aligned:

```
   fcdec:       d503201f        nop
   fcdf0:       d503201f        nop
   fcdf4:       d503201f        nop
   fcdf8:       d503201f        nop
   fcdfc:       d503201f        nop
   fce00:       f86478c5        ldr     x5, [x6, x4, lsl #3]
   fce04:       f8647807        ldr     x7, [x0, x4, lsl #3]
   fce08:       f8647868        ldr     x8, [x3, x4, lsl #3]
   fce0c:       8b070107        add     x7, x8, x7
   fce10:       8b0500e5        add     x5, x7, x5
   fce14:       f82478c5        str     x5, [x6, x4, lsl #3]
   fce18:       91000484        add     x4, x4, #0x1
   fce1c:       eb04003f        cmp     x1, x4
   fce20:       54ffff0c        b.gt    fce00
```

Here we add few nops for making it aligned and that should improve the performance. But actually we have a big performance degradation here. I tried to understand the reason, using the perf tool and top-down analysis, but it did no gave me any usable results. I just see, that in the aligned version the same code has more backend-bound stalls.

What is the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Nice, I have demonstrated this a number of times here.  There are a few factors that play into this first off need to confirm your measurement solution and confirm you are not instead creating issues with time measurement vs alignment and prefetch

Comment: with alignment a processor like this will fetch lets say 4 instructions at a time. so if you have a loop with 10 instructions they can be aligned across three fetch lines, but if the first instruction is the fourth one in a fetch line then it is four fetches per loop not three which will be noticed with a high performance instruction set like arm

Comment: also branch prediction and when and where it sees this unconditional branch also helps to start one of the fetches early making it perform better

Comment: in your last case you have the  branch it appears at the start of a new fetch line which doesnt mean an extra fetch but in this case I expect it to mean the branch predictor does not help start the fetch early

Comment: try other alignments with branch prediction turned off and this branch at other locations in the fetch line and see how it compares to this last one in your question, likewise how does it perform for each alignment with branch prediction.

Comment: to really see alignment, branch prediction, fetching, get the loads and stores out of the loop, do a directed test.

Comment: also confirm that changing the alignment of this code does not affect other code (like for example the code that measures time)   it generally does.  changing one function in the program affects all other functions liked after it in the binary from an alignment perspective.

Comment: Possibly due to cache trashing (i.e. loading data to the hottest cache flush the code due to conflict misses) though it is not very likely? Note that the loop is scalar while it can be vectorized if your CPU has SIMD units.

Comment: for cache thrashing and not with some other code not shown (thread/task whatever) would need a integrated cache with this code interfering with these specific addresses.yes?

Comment: @old_timer the code and data can conflicts if data is stored in the L2/L3 cache and not the L1 any-more. The L1 is often statically partitioned so this should not happen in the L1. IDK what is the size of the items but `10000` is quite big and the 3 arrays needs to be loaded in the cache so 32-bit items would results in 120_000 bytes loaded. Most L1 cache are significantly smaller than that so it can cause L1 data miss and thus possibly conflict misses. I assume the L1 is included in the L2. It would be even worst with 64-bit items.

Comment: okay yes I see. to get some performance changing thrashing though you need some striping to cause a thrashing that changes based on code alignment for this tiny loop

Comment: not remotely enough info from the OP on this one.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll give some comments on the discussion. The test in the topic is one of few directed tests. It contains only code for the loop counting and some code for time measurement. So, I assume, that the test is not affected by any other side effects. About the fetch of the b.gt instruction - the documentation says, that if cmp and taken branch are located sequentially, they are fetched in the same cycle, even if they are in different fetch lines.

Comment: I have other examples (for example, same loop unrolled by 2) where branch is located in the next line, but the alignment makes test faster. About branch prediction - perf says, that branch mispredict events decreased. About turning off branch predictor - I will try to understand, if I can turn it off. It should be an interesting experiment. About SIMD - as I know, this processor can not do such things. Speaking about cache thrashing - why should alignment influence it?

Comment: Alignment here may influence the timings (for example when the code is fetched) so the CPU can have few more cycle left to execution instructions (the first of the loop) and can also influence conflicting misses due to a different load order. This this a wild guess and unlikely but I do not have better explanations so far... Branch prediction on modern high-end CPUs can be affected by the position of the instruction but it does not cross 2 cache lines and is aligned to 32-bits and it is a hot loop so it is unlikely due to that.

Comment: Having more profiling informations and the CPU reference can help to understand better what is going on (the ISA does not really define how things are executed).